# Does AUC Area Under Curve ROC depend on the number of original variables used in logistic regression? Does this impact reliability?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, roc, auc

okay so I am using R(programme) to create a landslide susceptibility map - this map considers several parameters to create the map i.e. slope angle, bedrock geology. So I wanted to test the ability of the model to correctly predict whether landslides occur in the identified areas or not (0=don't occur and 1=occur). From that I produced the AUC ROC curve which produced the 0.85 outcome. I then removed the "slope angle" factor from the map (by repeating the whole thing again but excluding slope angle), and produced another AUC ROC curve with a value of 0.76. What I want to find out is if this second calculation can be used as reliably as the first, based on the fact that I have used one less parameter

Comment: What does it mean to calculate AUC "with" variables? Presumably you are fitting some model and the AUC is measuring classification performance? What kind of model? What is the role of these variables?

Comment: sorry, I suppose I mean that I'm calculating the ROC using variates (?), and from there I am calculating the AUC. I am unfamiliar with the exact terms to use so sorry if my question is not clear. In reality, I am just trying to find out whether the reliability of the AUC is changed by the number of variates considered in the ROC?

Comment: Sorry, but (to me) "calculating the ROC using variates" is  not clear. Could you explain what you are actually doing  (there are tags "logistic" and "regression", is this question about logistic regression? If so, please mention that in the question)

Comment: okay so I am using R(programme) to create a landslide susceptibility map - this map considers several variables to create the map i.e. slope angle, bedrock geology. So I wanted to test the ability of the model to correctly predict whether landslides occur in the identified areas or not (0=don't occur and 1=occur). From that I produced the AUC ROC curve which produced the 0.85 outcome. I then removed the "slope angle" factor from the map (by repeating the whole thing again but excluding slope angle), and produced another AUC ROC curve with a value of 0.76. What I want to find out is if this ..

Comment: ... second calculation can be used as reliably as the first, based on the fact that I have used one less factor/variable/variate or whatever they are called.

Comment: What do you mean by, "if this second calculation can be used as reliably as the first"? Are you asking if the 2 models are likely to be equally good at predicting landslides? Are you asking if the AUC tends to decrease when variables are dropped from the model the AUC is based on? Are you asking about how the standard error (sample to sample variability) of the AUC is affected by the number of variables in the model it's based on? Something else?

Comment: @Albany consider posting another question describing the data you have collected, the question you are trying to answer, and how you propose to do it. The AUC is likely not the measure you need.

Comment: @gung thanks for your response - the question i'm asking is if the 2 models are likely to be equally good at predicting landslides?

Answer (score 1):

The increase in reliability comes from a combination of overfitting and greater predictive accuracy. Provided you can theoretically estimate such a model, there is no upper bound on how many covariates you might include until you achieve a deterministic and perfect model for the outcome.

Comment: And keep in mind that the concordance probability ($c$-index; AUROC) is not a gold standard measure.  The log likelihood is the gold standard for computed measures of predictive information.

Comment: Thanks Adam, so does this mean that the 0.76 AUC value is as reliable as 0.85 despite fewer variables?

Comment: @Albany it cannot be determined. The simplest step to improving the quality of this analysis would be to validate the measure in bootstrapped data. Expect lower values.

Comment: @Albany, a word of warning: this is the correct answer to *a* question, but it may or may not be the answer to *your* question. From your apparent level of understanding of the issues, I'm not sure if you would recognize if this is answering a different question from what you may want to ask. We need to clarify what you are really asking.